# How to add a javascript function call in a file built from php echo statement

Tags: javascript, php

Writing this page I get values from a database and then create a page using PHP. It has a column with a button with an onclick="colorRed('line1'). I can't figure how to escape this correctly to make the call to the function work. If I do it outside the PHP form build it works fine so I am sure it is the way I am building the file. Please take a look and give me any advice you can. Here is the code snippit from the PHP section:

```
echo "<form name=\"form1\" action=\"save_special_announcement.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Line 1: <input id=\"line1\" size=\"39\" maxlength=\"38\" type=\"text\" value=\"" .$row['line1']. "\"/>
<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"colorRed('line1')\" name=\"button1\" value=\"Red\">";
```

Here is the simple function colorRed() calls (obviously it changes the text to red):

```
function colorRed(input) { // Change text to red
  document.getElementById(input).style.color = 'red'; };
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: use string interpolation: `onclick=\"colorRed('$input')\" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll be much happier if you enclose your strings with single quotes because then you don't need to escape all those doubles and your task is automatically simpler like this:

```
echo '<form name="form1" action="save_special_announcement.php" method="post">';
echo 'Line 1: <input id="line1" size="39" maxlength="38" type="text" value="' . $row['line1'] . '"/>';
echo '<input type="button" onclick="colorRed('line1')" name="button1" value="Red">';
```

Of course, you'll notice that the last line is still not properly escaped. But it's much simpler now. You only need to escape the single quotes like so:

```
echo '<input type="button" onclick="colorRed(\'line1\')" name="button1" value="Red">';
```

As a bonus, here's a tip about `echo`: use only one `echo` statement and use `,` instead of `.` for slightly better performance:

```
echo '<form name="form1" action="save_special_announcement.php" method="post">',
     'Line 1: <input id="line1" size="39" maxlength="38" type="text" value="', $row['line1'], '"/>',
     '<input type="button" onclick="colorRed(\'line1\')" name="button1" value="Red">';
```

Also, if you are not doing so already, make sure that the value of `$row['line1']` is properly encoded (with `htmlspecialchars()`). If it contains ampersand, double quote, or some other characters and it is not encoded, you will have trouble.